# How to run a Junit file in build.xml

Tags: ant, junit, junit4, build.xml

I need to run a junit file from ant build.xml, where junit resides in testscripts package and  junit class has been extended by other class which resides in another package called supportlibraries , 
now to how to run my junit through build.xml

can any help me out 
Thanks

Comment: Start with the ANT doco on Junit: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Mark O'Connor suggested, you need to set up your dependencies in your junit task.

```
<junit ....> 
  <classpath>
     <pathelement path="testscripts" />
     <pathelement path="supportlibraries">
     <!-- Add other dependencies here. -->
  </classpath>
  <test name ="...">
  </test>
</junit>
```